# Why is vertex snap not working

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, vertices, snapping

Snap does not work if the mesh is behind another model.

As far as I remember, this was not the case in previous versions, and in X-Ray mode it was possible to use snap, no matter how many meshes were in front of the selected object.
Is there a way to get the old settings back?

[image]

On the screenshot: I'm trying to position the vertex in the Y axis in the same position as the bottom vertex, but due to the mesh blocking the view, I can't do it.

Comment: I can confirm that something has changed. It works fine in Blender 3.5 but not in 3.6 with exactly the same settings on the vertex snapping dropdown. Suggest you report it as a bug via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.

Comment: Same issue with 3.6. No bug report filed yet :(

Comment: I just downloaded 3.6.1 and the issue seems to be fixed.